# Can resources carry multiple agents in Anylogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

In the below image I am using AGV as resources to carry Containers(agents) in the rackStore and rack Pick blocks. By default, one AGV carries only one agent; Is it possible to set agent carrying capacity of resources such that it can carry multiple agents?

[image: Img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just use the Batch element before the pickup and batch your containers together. Then, the AGV will pickup a batch, i.e. several containers.